# RegEx word boundary with special character

Tags: regex

I need the words with special characters to be replaced.
Example:

```
Regex.Replace("Cap' sa* zeesa*total", @"\bsa*\b", "----") is not working.
```

Output:

```
"Cap' ---- zeesatotal"
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` has a special meaning in regex, to replace a literal `*` character you need to use `\*` in the regex or put it inside of a character class.

You also need to drop the `\b` at the end, because it will only match between word characters and non-word characters.  This means that it will not match between the `*` and the space in your string.  You could also change this to `\B` if you do not want to match when the character directly after the `*` is a word character.

Try changing your regex to the following:

```
@"\bsa\*"
```

Or alternatively:

```
@"\bsa[*]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
/(?:(?<!\w)([*]\w*+|\w+[*]\w*+))/
```