# How to make `\b` in regex behave as if `\w=\S` and `\W=\s`?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need to match word boundaries using C++ Regex (ECMAscript or whatever), but in this particular situation I find myself, the criteria for what is considered a word-char must be changed.

By default, `\w` = `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and `\W` = `[^\w]`.

But sometimes situations dictate that special chars like `?`,`!`,`,`, etc also be considered word-chars.

**Basically, I would be happy if `\b` was tricked into thinking that `\w` is `\S` and that `\W` is `\s`.**

Is there a way to do it?

P.S. I'm currently trying to simulate this and expressions are looking ugly. Would be nice if I get `\b` to behave as I want. **Also, it would be nice if the new definition of `\b` is only activated where I want, and at other places, the original definition of `\b` should be used.**

---

The closest question which I could manage to find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15907896/4334743). The OP wanted to end the expression with a `\b`, but could not because `*` is not a word-char. What if he still wanted to end it with a word-boundary but `*` treated as a word-char ?

Comment: You could write your own regex engine.

Comment: The answer is - indtall Boost and use lookbehind `(?<!\S` and lookahead `(?!\S)` instead of  `\bword\b`.

Comment: For the boundary after the word you can use lookahead, replacing `\b` with `(?=\s)`. Unfortunatly, C++11 does not support lookbehind, so you cannot do the same for the first boundary.

Comment: How about `const std::string specialWord = "[A-Za-z0-9_?!,]"; const std::string notSpecialWord = "[^A-Za-z0-9_?!,]";` and use these helper variables to construct your regexes ?

Comment: @Jarod42 because `\b` doesn't consume character